# How does free checkout work in Opencart 2?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to make a development site where I can add products to my cart and delivery options - and then checkout. I want to be able to do dummy orders without using real cards or payment gateways

I have enabled free checkout but it does not appear on the OpenCart admin panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenCart, Free Checkout payment option only show up when **order total equals to zero**.

> To enable/disable Free Checkout: /Admin => Extensions => Payments => Free Checkout

Remember, it's only show up when **Total = 0**

To test it, try to add $0 item and select $0 shipping (or you can enable Free Shipping option)

To allow test orders submit without any credit card info, you can install and enable **Cash On Delivery** payment method.

> To enable/disable Cash On Delivery: /Admin => Extensions => Payments => Cash On Delivery

Comment: The cash on delivery option was a perfect choice for us. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So when you order it should finish your order without costing any shipping?

If that is was your are asking than go to shipping section open free shipping (or install it if you have not) set the price to 0 and that's about it?

Or am i not understanding your question?